# Can we use standard xcode-build argument in xctool?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using xctool to make app building automate on the server. Whenever we want to test the app , we make a build with specific provision { in some case with pem }.

I found xcode build have this argument -exportProvisioningProfile and can we use it with xctool too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/blob/master/scripts/build.sh), I would say no.

Happily though, it's open source, so you can change it so it does whatever you like.